# Android Converting XML to Json Error passing through webservice

Tags: java, android, json, xml, web-services

I want to sync my SQLite database on android device with SQL Server Data. I am using Webservice developed in Visual Studio.

The Webservice is returning XML which I am getting from

```
client.get("http://10.0.2.2/WebApi/api/mpapi/GetAllWriting", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
```

Now I am passing the response to extract JSON array from it.

```
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    try {
        // Extract JSON array from the response
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
        System.out.println(arr.length());
```

I am getting the following error.

> Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONArray.toString()

The value in response is

> [{"Id":1,"Title":"Danish","Des":"Khan"},{"Id":2,"Title":"Rayan","Des":"Linkon"}]

What is the error is the XML not formatted properly? DO I need to change the Webservice./ Please guide as I have mostly copied the coding from multiple locations.

Comment: r u getting xml or json from ur queston it seems json but u have written xml plz clarifiy

Comment: Are you sure that response is exactly that you showed above? The error you mentioned might happen if you try to parse a json which is not an array as `JSONArray`

Answer (score 0):

From your question it doesn't seems that you are getting xml data from your web service, however if in case you are sure that the response is xml you can try this [Download java-json.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm). Add it into your library folder and get json object by executing the following code.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = null;

jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(yourXmlObject);
```

You will need to import `org.json.JSONObject; org.json.JSONException; org.json.XML;` in order to execute above code.